# MomentJS, issue with hours and queries

Tags: momentjs

I get an issue when I try to implement Moment on my NodeJS application...

The date posted by the user : 1894-01-01 09:03:00

The date in the query : 1894-01-01 08:03:00

When I use moment to parse this date, the hour get -1 and I don't know why...

My code :

```
var start = moment(a.startmonth+'-'+a.startday+'-'+a.startyear+' '+a.starthour+':'+a.startminute, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");
```

Comment: what about `moment.utc(Number[]); moment.utc(String); moment.utc(String, String); `

Comment: It works with `moment.utc()` ! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `moment.utc(Number[]); moment.utc(String); moment.utc(String, String);`

In UTC mode all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

```
moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
Additionally, while in UTC mode, all getters and setters will internally use the Date#getUTC* and Date#setUTC* methods instead of the Date#get* and Date#set* methods.
```

[read more](http://momentjs.com/docs/)